# split a pyspark.sql dataFrame into multiple tables based on one column

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Given a pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame x:

`name    day earnings    revenue
Oliver   1   100         44
Oliver   2   200         69
John     1   144         11
John     2   415         54
John     3   33          10
John     4   82          82`

Is it possible to split the table into two tables based on the name column (that acts as an index), and nest the two tables under the same object (not sure about the exact terms to use). So in the example above, tables[0] will be:

`name    day earnings    revenue
Oliver  1   100         44
Oliver  2   200         69`

and tables[1] will be:

`name    day earnings    revenue
John    1   144         11
John    2   415         54
John    3   33          10
John    4   82          82`

Note that that the number of rows in each 'sub-table' may vary.

I have tried the following: `dict(tuple(x.groupby('name')))` which works great with a Pandas dataframe, but when I try to do the same on a pyspark.sql dataframe I get the error : `TypeError: 'GroupedData' object is not iterable`

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You can go like this,

```
uniq_names = [x.asDict().values()[0] for x in df.select("name").distinct().collect()]
tables = [df.where(df.name == x) for x in uniq_names]
```

Comment: Did you find the answer useful?